# ¿Cómo sacar el mínimo y el máximo de cada n filas, junto con la fecha de los datos?

Tags: r

Tengo una data frame con más 10 años de datos cada 30 minutos, con 31 columnas (más de 100000 datos), por lo que necesito obtener los mínimos y máximos cada 48 datos de cada columna, este dato debe estar junto a la fecha en el cual se obtuvo dicho máximo y el mínimo. Espero su ayuda.. Gracias.
[image: Este imagen es un ejemplo de los datos que estan en el data frame]

Comment: Bienvenida Daniela a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta una muestra de los datos, como texto y no como captura, así va a ser más sencillo responderte.

Comment: Por cierto, lo que parece que buscas es el máximo valor por día no?

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios Patricio. Y respondiendo a tu pregunta si exacto seria el mínimo y el máximo de cada día. Los datos vienen cada media hora y necesito el datos de media hora máximo y mínimo y a lado la fecha de cuando sucedió ese evento.

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que tus datos se llaman `data` y una columna `V.Batt.Volt` puedes probar con esto:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(V.Batt.Volt == max(data$V.Batt.Volt))
```

de esa forma obtienes la fila completa donde ocurre ese evento y podrás ver la fecha y hora, para ayudarte mejor debieras poner un extracto de tus datos, no entiendo cuando dices 48 filas, si por ejemplo tienes solo 48 filas o tienes muchas más y cada día tiene 48 filas. Por eso es tan importante tener un ejemplo de los datos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Son en total como 10 años de datos cada 30 minutos, con 31 columnas (más de 10000 datos), por lo que necesito obtener los mínimos y máximos cada 48 datos de cada columna.

Comment: te recomiendo entonces editar tu pregunta para que se entienda bien y puedas recibir mejor ayuda por parte de los usuarios

Comment: Gracias por tus recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo unos datos como estos (similares a los que has descripto):

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-29", tz='GMT')
end <- start + as.difftime(5, units="days")

df <- data.frame(Fecha = seq(from=start, by=60*30, to=end),
                 V1 = runif(241),
                 V2 = runif(241))
head(df)
               Fecha         V1        V2
1 2015-01-29 00:00:00 0.73847990 0.3106750
2 2015-01-29 00:30:00 0.46992810 0.7890854
3 2015-01-29 01:00:00 0.61051499 0.4920094
4 2015-01-29 01:30:00 0.78236306 0.6912806
5 2015-01-29 02:00:00 0.07659569 0.3321352
6 2015-01-29 02:30:00 0.14292364 0.3858232
```

Usando `dplyr/tidyverse` se me ocurre hacer lo siguiente:

```
library("tidyverse")

df %>% 
  group_by(Fecha.Grupo=as.Date(Fecha)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(V1:V2), funs(which.min, which.max)) %>% 
  gather("Valor", "Fila.Grupo", -Fecha.Grupo) %>% 
  arrange(Fecha.Grupo) -> indice

indice
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   Fecha.Grupo Valor        Fila.Grupo
   <date>      <chr>             <int>
 1 2015-01-29  V1_which.min          9
 2 2015-01-29  V2_which.min         43
 3 2015-01-29  V1_which.max         44
 4 2015-01-29  V2_which.max          4
 5 2015-01-30  V1_which.min         45
 6 2015-01-30  V2_which.min         37
 7 2015-01-30  V1_which.max         47
 8 2015-01-30  V2_which.max          8
 9 2015-01-31  V1_which.min         16
10 2015-01-31  V2_which.min         26
# … with 14 more rows
```

Con esto generamos una especie de índice, que nos indica para cada día (La fecha sin la hora) en que filas se encuentra el valor máximo y mínimo de cada variable. Esto es fácil de escalar, ya que simplemente debes modificar la definición de a que variables aplicaremos las funciones: `vars(V1:V2)` en este caso definimos que se aplica a la `V1` y hasta la `V2`.

Con este índice, solo resta numerar las filas de cada día de 1 a 48 y mediante un `inner_join` seleccionar solo las que coinciden con nuestro `indice`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Fecha.Grupo=as.Date(Fecha)) %>% 
  group_by(Fecha.Grupo) %>% 
  mutate(Fila.Grupo=row_number()) %>% 
  inner_join(indice, by = c("Fecha.Grupo", "Fila.Grupo"))

# A tibble: 24 x 6
# Groups:   Fecha.Grupo [6]
   Fecha                    V1      V2 Fecha.Grupo Fila.Grupo Valor   
   <dttm>                <dbl>   <dbl> <date>           <int> <chr>   
 1 2015-01-29 01:30:00 0.464   0.976   2015-01-29           4 V2_whic…
 2 2015-01-29 04:00:00 0.0246  0.501   2015-01-29           9 V1_whic…
 3 2015-01-29 21:00:00 0.649   0.0305  2015-01-29          43 V2_whic…
 4 2015-01-29 21:30:00 0.994   0.676   2015-01-29          44 V1_whic…
 5 2015-01-30 03:30:00 0.398   0.982   2015-01-30           8 V2_whic…
 6 2015-01-30 18:00:00 0.256   0.00639 2015-01-30          37 V2_whic…
 7 2015-01-30 22:00:00 0.0198  0.430   2015-01-30          45 V1_whic…
 8 2015-01-30 23:00:00 0.981   0.457   2015-01-30          47 V1_whic…
 9 2015-01-31 07:30:00 0.00985 0.568   2015-01-31          16 V1_whic…
10 2015-01-31 10:30:00 0.994   0.146   2015-01-31          22 V1_whic…
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información... Probaré lo que me comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que necesitas las sumarias de datos de cada 48 filas porque esas componen las medidas de un día en tu tabla. Diciéndolo de otra manera sería que necesitas el mínimo y el máximo de cada día para una de tus variables.

### Setup

Utilizo el código de Patricio usó para generar su tabla de muestra, sólo que en lugar de `data.frame()` uso `tibble()` para aprovechar su formato de impresión.

```r
library(dplyr)

start <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-29", tz='GMT')
end <- start + as.difftime(5, units="days")

df <- tibble(Fecha = seq(from=start, by=60*30, to=end),
                 V1 = runif(241),
                 V2 = runif(241))
print(df)
```

```
# A tibble: 241 x 3
   Fecha                   V1     V2
   <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2015-01-29 00:00:00 0.0852 0.315 
 2 2015-01-29 00:30:00 0.759  0.0192
 3 2015-01-29 01:00:00 0.652  0.882 
 4 2015-01-29 01:30:00 0.950  0.798 
 5 2015-01-29 02:00:00 0.555  0.854 
 6 2015-01-29 02:30:00 0.119  0.112 
 7 2015-01-29 03:00:00 0.805  0.966 
 8 2015-01-29 03:30:00 0.701  0.336 
 9 2015-01-29 04:00:00 0.960  0.782 
10 2015-01-29 04:30:00 0.144  0.244 
# … with 231 more rows
```

Al mismo tiempo, veo que el formato de tus datos está en *dd/mm/yyyy* por lo que te recomiendo que uses `dmy_hms()` para pasarlos a clase *datetime*.

```r
library(lubridate)

dmy_hms("1/1/2015 00:00:30")
```

```
[1] "2015-01-01 00:00:30 UTC"
```

### Desarrollo

Pienso que la mejor manera de hacerlo es usando `summarise_all()` y luego unir por filas. En mi caso primero creo la función `mi_sumaria()` que toma la variable `Fecha` para agrupar después de haberla convertido en *Date* (nuevamente, pensando en que necesitas los resúmenes por día). Se agrega una columna al final para identificar la función de resumen utilizada.

```r
mi_sumaria <- function(tabla, funcion){
  
  tabla %>% 
    mutate(Fecha = as.Date(Fecha))  %>%
    group_by(Fecha) %>% 
    summarise_all(funcion) %>% 
    mutate(categoria = funcion)
}
```

Lo bueno de esta función es que sirve para cualquier variable de resumen, siempre y cuando no necesites agregarle parámetros extra (tipo `na.rm`).

Luego de esto es sólo cuestión de juntar por filas las tablas obtenidas. Lo bueno de haber creado la función `mi_sumaria()` es que lo puedes hacer en una sola línea sin necesidad de crear otros objetos.

```r
bind_rows(mi_sumaria(df, "min"), mi_sumaria(df, "max"))
```

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   Fecha           V1      V2 categoria
   <date>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    
 1 2015-01-29 0.0415  0.00860 min      
 2 2015-01-30 0.00327 0.0196  min      
 3 2015-01-31 0.0122  0.0199  min      
 4 2015-02-01 0.00772 0.00119 min      
 5 2015-02-02 0.0179  0.0231  min      
 6 2015-02-03 0.222   0.902   min      
 7 2015-01-29 0.985   0.966   max      
 8 2015-01-30 0.991   0.988   max      
 9 2015-01-31 0.992   0.992   max      
10 2015-02-01 0.971   0.999   max      
11 2015-02-02 0.997   0.960   max      
12 2015-02-03 0.222   0.902   max
```

La función `mi_sumaria()` funciona siempre y cuando las columnas que no son la fecha con la que agrupas sean todas numéricas, sin importar cuántas columnas tengas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Samuel.